# Slice and array after desired string

Tags: javascript

I have an array in which I have strings, in this I want to slice the array after I get `"test?"`, but my logic of slicing isn't working.

```js
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
let output = input.slice(input.indexOf('?') + 1, input.length);
console.log(output);
```

Desired Output:

```
["test?","yes"]
```

Comment: nothing has only `'?'` in it. more details please

Comment: @DanielA.White can you look at the array and tell me that again? I think I made it clear in my question. i'm assuming

Comment: do you need `indexOf('test?')`

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the index of the array element where `?` is there, then we can slice it, also this will find the first occurrence only!

```js
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
let output = input.slice(input.findIndex(x => x.includes('?')) + 1, input.length);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: adding `input.length -1` gets me my output, your output is so fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find from the element which ends with `?` here you are:

```
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
const indexToSliceFrom = input.findIndex(x => x.endsWith('?'));
let output = input.slice(indexToSliceFrom + 1, input.length);
console.log(output);
```

If not ends with, but contains, use `includes` method instead `endsWith`:

```
const indexToSliceFrom = input.findIndex(x => x.includes('?'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that only ? isn't anywhere.
`IndexOf` method search for a string in the array that doesn't exist.
If you want to slice after `test?`, you have to check the entire string

```
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
let output = input.slice(input.indexOf('test?') + 1, input.length);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to search based on a regex pattern and not the exact string, I believe this is what you need:

```js
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
let output = input.slice(input.findIndex(value => /\?/.test(value)) + 1);
console.log(output);
```

input.indexOf('?') is not getting at match as this function requires exact match.

If you want to match the exact string 'test?', then you could do the following:

```js
let input = ['hello', 'choose', 'test1', 'test?', 'yes,', 'no'];
let output = input.slice(input.indexOf('test?') + 1, input.length);
console.log(output);
```